# Wait for .zip file to extract before copying it's contents elsewhere programmaticaly

Tags: c#, zip, unzip

I'm trying to write a small console app tool that unzips an archive containing multiple files/folders/other archives and arrange it's contents in another way.

I unzip the root file with `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` method from `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` library:

```
public static void UnzipPackage(string packagePath, string targetPath) 
{
    try
    {
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(packagePath, targetLocation);
        Console.WriteLine("Unzipping file {0} complete.", packagePath);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directory was not found.");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File was not found.");
    }
}
```

After running this method on my package, I want to copy a file which was in this package in a subfolder.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I do this:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(targetLocation + @"READY\PHOTO"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetLocation + @"\READY\PHOTO");
}
if (Directory.Exists(targetLocation + @"\MAIN\PHOTO"))
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(targetLocation + @"\MAIN\PHOTO");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string destFile = Path.Combine(targetLocation + @"\MAIN\PHOTO", fileName);
        File.Copy(file, destFile, true);
    }
}
```

Both `MAIN` and `READY` are my subdirectories where whole package goes ("main") and sorted files go ("ready").

However, when running this, the zip file is not yet unzipped - an exception occurs showing it can't access the file specified even though it grabbed it's name from `Directory.GetFiles()`. The folder created when unzipping the zip file shows only after I terminate my console app (no wonder it can't access it).

So the big question is - how can I wait for the unzipped folder to show up? I tried using `Thread.Sleep()`, but it doesn't affect the flow anyhow - an exception still occurs, and the folder shows only after I terminate the app.

Comment: Can you show the full code example so we can see how the 2 pieces of code fit together, instead of looking unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your getting an IOException something like "The process cannot access the file...because it is being used by another process."

It looks to me that there is a problem in your copy method. It looks like your from and to paths are essentially the same. So the system cannot overwrite the file, because you currently have it open for reading.

Just to be clear - the issue is not related to unzipping! In the example you have written the variable `file` and `destFile` are going to be the same - and they need to be different.

Comment: Oh my. A silly copy&paste error which was driving me nuts for like hours. Thanks for spotting this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
string destFile = Path.Combine(targetLocation + @"\MAIN\PHOTO", fileName);
```

Should be:

```
string destFile = Path.Combine(targetLocation + @"\READY\PHOTO", fileName);
```

You're attempting to copy the file to the same location.

Comment: Your's and Matt's answer are basically the same, however he was faster by circa 15 minutes, so the green tick goes to him. Upvoted your answer though to appreciate your contribution.